# paytm integeration release build crash

Tags: android, android-studio, paytm

After integrating Paytm payments sdk, debug version is working properly but release build is crashing when getting the response from Paytm.

```
if minifyEnabled false means release build working fine, but must need minifyEnabled is true. 
minifyEnabled true means com.pay.project.Paytm.PaytmWebview.a(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
```

---

Error Log:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.pay.project.android.test, PID: 23149 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
    No static method wrap(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lorg/b/c;
         or its super classes (declaration of 'org.b.c' appears in 
/data/app/com.pay.project.android.test-1/base.apk) at com.pay.project.Paytm.PaytmWebview.a(Unknown Source) `at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:822)`at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5774)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)
```

Comment: Please send any log crash if you have

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process: com.pay.project.android.test, PID: 23149   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method wrap(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lorg/b/c; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.b.c' appears in /data/app/com.pay.project.android.test-1/base.apk)   at com.pay.project.Paytm.PaytmWebview.a(Unknown Source)

Comment: post full logcat please

Comment: error log was added.

Answer (score 0):

paytm gradel file changes to previous version of paytm, now it working fine.